# What is the cypress cy.contains() equivalent in webdriverio?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, webdriver-io

I have mainly worked with cypress previously for e2e automated testing, I have now started working on webdriverIO. So for a cypress command such as

```js
cy.get("[data-testid='nav-bar']").contains("Search Box").click();
```

What would be the equivalent for this in webdriverIO? I have tried the following approach in a PageObject Model.

```js
class HomePage extends Page {
    get navBar() {
      return browser.$("[data-testid='nav-bar']");
    }
    
    openSearchBox() {
      this.navBar().click('//*[text="Search Box"]');
    }
}
```

However, this approach does not seem to work, any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving Page Objects asside for now, you'd type this in WebdriverIO:

```js
const bar = $('[data-testid='nav-bar']');
expect(bar.getText()).toInclude('Search Box');
bar.click();
```

You can use chai for the assertion instead of Jest Matchers:

```js
const expectChai = require('chai').expect;
// ...
expectChai(bar.getText()).to.have.string('Search Box');
// ...
```

Comment: I'd not recommend using chai. Please use built-in expect assertion library https://webdriver.io/docs/api/expect-webdriverio.html#tohavetext

Answer (score 0):

The exact analog to

```js
cy.get("[data-testid='nav-bar']").contains("Search Box").click();
```

can be achieved with xpath selector

```
$("[data-testid='nav-bar']").$("./*[descendant-or-self::*[contains(text(), 'Search Box')]]").click();
```

It looks a bit ugly though, consider adding a [custom command](https://webdriver.io/docs/customcommands.html) that would mimic Cypress's `contains`:

```
// put this to `before` hook in your wdio.conf.js
browser.addCommand('cyContains', function(text) {
  this.waitForExist()
  return this.$(`./*[descendant-or-self::*[contains(text(), '${text}')]]`)
}, true)

$("[data-testid='nav-bar']").cyContains("Search Box").click();
```

P.S.
Check out the selector in the browser console right on this page, paste in the browser console

```
$x("//span[descendant-or-self::*[contains(text(), 'Search Box')]]")
```